# Bootstrap 4 Modal Open/close causes image position changing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I have following simple code snippet that opens a bs4 modal through a button.

The button appears by hovering the container.

The issue is that after the open the modal through the button and then close. The image moves up unexpectedly. The position of the image can be restored by hover the container again. I just wonder why this behavior happens and how to fix it.

https://jsfiddle.net/hb6n71zg/1/ code snippet link.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.p-img {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.p-capt {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.container:hover .p-img {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .p-capt {
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<h2>TOPTOPTOP</h2>
<p>TOPTOPTOPTOPTOP</p>

<div class="container">
  <img class="p-img w-100" src="https://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/google-logo.jpg" />
  <div class="p-capt">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-100" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">launch modal</button>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update:

If I trig the modal through javascript, this weird behavior would not happen.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-100">launch modal</button>

$(function(){
    $("button").click(function() {
    $("#myModal").modal('toggle');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with a very weird combination between three different conditions:

- `.container` having `overflow: hidden;`
- `.container` having content overflowing
- `.container` not being `:hover`ed unless you move the mouse, when the modal closes.

The solution is to remove the `overflow:hidden` from `.container` and obtain the button clipping effect of the button by using the button's own container (`.p-cont`):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.p-img {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  height: auto;
}

.p-capt {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.p-capt .btn-primary {
  position: relative;
  left: -15px;
}

.container:hover .p-img {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .p-capt {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 38px;
}


/* this removes the button's outline when active, as IMHO it didn't look right (it was cut off by the overflow:hidden. Totatlly optional, of course */

.p-capt .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,
.p-capt .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.p-capt .show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle:focus,
.p-capt .btn-primary.focus,
.p-capt .btn-primary:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<h2>TOPTOPTOP</h2>
<p>TOPTOPTOPTOPTOP</p>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img class="p-img d-block w-100 h-auto" src="https://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/google-logo.jpg" />
      <div class="p-capt">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">launch modal</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: I also used Bootstrap `v4.4.1` instead of your `v4.0.0` but it doesn't affect the example. I just wanted to make sure that's not the cause and didn't bother to change it back.

Comment: I tried out your solution but it seems like there are some issues with small width screen. The scroll bar keep switching between on or off otherwise everything is fine.  I will go for the simple JS option so I don't have to worry about other compatibility issues (size/browser wise) as well as I have to use JS ultimately. but your solution definitely offers some thought.

The only thing I'm not sure this issue is an expected behavior or something I miss about the right way to use BS feature. Probably open an issue in Github page later.

Comment: @Yunhai, scrollbar switching on/off is normal Bootstrap behavior. When opening modal, bootstrap adds a class to body which applies `overflow:hidden` and it gets removed when modal is closed. This is so that scrolling inside the modal does not scroll the page under the modal instead. It has absolutely nothing to do with your current question (other than they are both about Bootstrap).

Comment: Also note it is recommended that direct children of `.container` are `.row`s and direct children of `.row`s are `.col-*-*`s. I updated the example. I also remove the `min-height` from `body`, which is not necessary for the answer, it's just something I tried when I was trying to figure out how to fix your issue and forgot to remove.

Comment: I mean the scrollbar on/off on hover under certain width, your update fixes the problem. I do know the general BS structure among `.row` , `.col` and `.container`,etc. That's why I felt a little bit weird for this case regarding to my original problem.